# Saving contents of a browser window to disk

Tags: ruby, watir

I was just wondering if there's an elegant way to save the browser contents (in my case a pdf file) to disk using a browser automated via Watir (navigate to a page, then "click" on a link to a pdf document)? I was hoping to do a "send_keys" on the browser object but it doesn't seem to work -- `browser.send_keys("+^S")`. I could use AutoIt but that requires that I find a window first (or did I get that wrong?) by title and I find that approach not quite reliable (in case there happens to be duplicate windows...)

Here's what the code looks like...

```
b=Watir::Browser.new
b.goto "http://somesite.com/somepage.htm" #assume this page contains a bunch of links
b.link(:text, /pdf/i).when_present.click #this action loads the pdf in the browser
b.send_keys("+^s") #try to invoke acrobat's "save as" <-- does NOT work!
```

The last line probably does not work because the Acrobat control may not be in focus and may not be receiving the intended keystrokes...

I know there are several options here as pointed out by Zeljko. But I was wondering how come I don't have access to the underlying document stream?

Comment: Maybe I'm not trying hard enough but I don't understand the parameters of your question. Sounds like you open a PDF somehow from within a web page, or maybe it builds a pdf. Then you need to save it? Which browser are you testing through (I am assuming that Watir is being using to test)?

Comment: @Dave -- Please allow me to rephrase. What would be the ideal way to download a file to disk (mimic ctrl+s) using Watir? I'm using the default driver (IE)  for now but don't want to get tied down to Windows for production.

Comment: You seem to be limiting this back to one way in one circumstance. How does the pdf come to be opened in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

To quote myself:

> The easiest solution is to disable the popup and download the file
>   automatically.

There are other solutions too: http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/File+Downloads

Comment: So is there no way I can directly access the underlying document stream on the browser object? You know like webBrowser.DocumentStream (.NET API) or perhaps, $m->content() (PERL Mechanize)

Answer (score 0):

I was successfull to send Ctrl-S to the browser (tested with firefox) with:

```
b.send_keys([:control, 's'])
```

But it does not help really. After this you are in the "Save As"-dialogue.
But you will not save the PDF, but the whole Website (maybe it depends on your browser settings).

To control this save as dialogue I used [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/):

```
    require 'win32ole'  #For AutoIt
    au3 = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
    wintitle = "Speichern unter"  #<-- adapt language specific text
    download_directory = File.join(Dir.pwd, "downloads")
    win_exists = au3.WinWait(wintitle, nil, 5)   
    if (win_exists > 0)
      au3.WinActivate(wintitle)
      au3.Send('!n')  #Dateiname
      au3.Send(download_directory.gsub(/\//, '\\'))
      sleep 1
      au3.Send('{ENTER}')
    end
```

Now I have a directory with containing my pdf and I can do:

```
    pdf_mask = "%s-Dateien/*.pdf" % download_directory #<- Again language specific
    Dir[pdf_mask].each{|pdf|
      #do something twith the file
    }
```

I'm new to AutoIt, maybe I find an easier way.

But I agree to the other answer:

> The easiest solution is to disable the popup and download the file automatically.